# Can't adjust screen brightness in settings or with Fn keys

Tags: brightness, settings, 22.10

I am using Ubuntu Unity on a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5 (14ARE05).  When I go to the 'Brightness and Lock' settings there are only options to adjust lock, not the brightness.  How do I fix this?  I already tried the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys, but they don't work.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v78TF.png)

Edit: I don't know if it is related to this particular problem, but as background, I am experiencing other issues, like <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key not working, wallpaper missing, etc.  I did run `echo "c" > /proc/sysrq-trigger` as a joke to trigger a kernel panic.  It seems to modify the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>/<kbd>SysEq</kbd> behavior, possibly creating these issues?

Comment: The screen brightness issue has been a long-standing problem with Ideapads. Unfortunately it has only one setting, as Lenovo has not yet made Linux drivers for the panel light 